# How can I write a populated JSP to the filesystem?

Tags: java, jsp, file-io

I have a legacy system that needs to produce a number of reports in a "batch" process.  I'd like to do this using a few JSP templates (i.e., a "header.jsp", a variable number of "body.jsp", and a "footer.jsp") to build a static HTML file that can be viewed later.  In Java, I want to:

- Open an HTML file for writing
- Write the output of `header.jsp` (populated with data) to the file
- For each report in the batch:

  - Populate the variables used by the template
  - Write the output of `body.jsp` (populated with data) to the file
- Write the output of `footer.jsp` to the file
- Close the file for writing

I know how to do this in a JSP to be displayed on screen (I'd just have a parent JSP that builds itself out of "includes"), but the question is: **How can I capture the JSP output and write it to a file in the filesystem?**

Comment: Why JSP? It requires a running servlet container. Why not another template engine? E.g. Thymeleaf, FreeMarker, Groovy, Jade4j, just to mention the major [template engines supported by Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines).

Comment: Well, it's part of an existing servlet application (in Struts 1!) and I already have the JSP prepared because these reports can also be viewed one at a time.  I hope to re-use as much code as possible for this batch process.  I would accept an answer that uses Thymeleaf or something else, if that's an easier or cleaner way to do it.

Comment: To re-use as much code as possible, simply have your batch program call the webapp using an HTTP connection.

Comment: Not a bad idea!  I'd still like an answer to the question posed, though.  I would guess that it's something like triggering the JSP and capturing its output as a stream, which can be written to a file.